# Ajax sending large data to server

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html

I have read the GET/POST request has either character or size limitations (2000 chars or some browsers 8 KB limit).

What is the correct way to send large data (5000 chars or more) using AJAX?

Thank you!

Comment: POST payloads do not have such limitations.

Answer (score 1):

As I know GET/POST max size depends on web server and client.
[maximum length of HTTP GET request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659952/maximum-length-of-http-get-request)